# jenkins: if the script has ever failed, then it will always be logged in Jenkins as a failure.

Tags: jenkins

if the script has ever failed, then it will always be logged in Jenkins as a failure. How do get around this problem?  I don't want to create/rename the workspace to get around this problem.  Is there a better solution.  I also don't want to delete the runhistory to resolve this.

Comment: Why do you want to change the build result? If it failed, that means for that particular build, it failed...

Comment: When I run the build again and everything worked fine it still says it failed.

Comment: Standard Jenkins: When you run the build again, that becomes a separate build with a separate build URL and build result. The status page should be updated to reflect that the latest status is a success.